Adding reveal.js presentations to an existing site?
I have several reveal.js presentations, and I want to host them online so that I can access them from anywhere, rather than just on my laptop.  I also host a blog site using the static engine Hugo, which serves up html pages.  Hugo has the concept of "pages": currently one page contains the blog posts, another one has a little bit about me, and another lists all the blog tags.  It would be easy to add a page called "presentations".
My presentations include text, mathematics with MathJax, and various interactive diagrams included as iframes.  It would be very nice to include everything in a single html file, with reveal.js material from a CDN such as
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js@5.1.0/dist/reveal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js@5.1.0/dist/reveal.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

I also have a few local files, such as my own theme.  I don't know whether the files above include plugins (for mathematics, menus, highlighting) or whether they have to included as well.
I appreciate that questions similar to this have been asked before, but most seem to be several years old, or involve github, which I'd rather avoid, since every time I attempt to use it I get caught up in an almighty tangle and confusion.  Anyway, I don't need version control or sharing, just an online presence.
Anyway, I'd be happy of any advice!

So you want to show multiple presentations in a single HTML file? Wouldn't it be much easier to have a "presentations" page that contains links to all the HTML files that contain the individual presentations and each link opens the corresponding presentation in a separate browser tab? That way you (and the "audience") would be able to share specific presentations by URL, too.

Thank you very much.  Yes, I should have made myself more clear - that is indeed what I want.  The real question I have is how to create each presentation as a stand-alone html file.  Or, if not, the minimum other files I'd need to add.

Apart from the content held in your HTML file (and maybe your custom CSS files and images), you will need the core of reveal.js. This contains the "dist" folder with css and js stuff along the themes and fonts, the "js" folder with more js stuff and the "plugin" folder with your selected ones. You can find all of them in your computer or in reveal.js's github. Be aware of the relative paths of your HTML files, that should point correctly to these other files.
